# Spark web UI doesn't update as app runs (on Yarn)

Tags: apache-spark, ambari

Our Spark web UI (when accessed from the Yarn UI or the Spark History Server) no longer updates when I reload the browser window when viewing a running Spark app (our apps run on a Hadoop/Yarn cluster in client mode).  This used to work with Spark 1.5.2, but after we upgraded to HDP 2.6.4 (hence Spark 1.6.3 and Spark 2.2.0), I now have to wait for the app to finish before the web UI updates (for both 1.6.3 and 2.2.0).

It seems that when I first look at an app in the Spark web UI, I get the current state.  But refreshing the browser window after that does not show any updates.  Only after the app finishes will refreshing the browser show any changes.  Normally it shows the final state, but sometimes it doesn't even show that.

Spark UI example screenshot:  (I apparently first loaded the page when the app was on stage 41.  Refreshing the browser shows no updates/changes while the app is running.  When the app finished, reloading the browser showed the final state--i.e., all stages complete.)

[image]

We set `spark.history.fs.update.interval` to `10s` in Ambari, hoping that might be related. That didn't seem to help. I looked on the master node that runs the history server, and it appears the Ambari change was pushed out:

```
# pwd
/usr/hdp/current
# grep -R "spark.history.fs.update.interval" *
spark-client/conf/spark-defaults.conf:spark.history.fs.update.interval 10s
spark-historyserver/conf/spark-defaults.conf:spark.history.fs.update.interval 10s
spark-thriftserver/conf/spark-defaults.conf:spark.history.fs.update.interval 10s
```

Another (I assume directly related) problem: From the Yarn/RM UI, clicking on the "ApplicationMaster" link for a running Spark App just hangs--the Spark UI does not show.  (I have to go to the Spark History server URL to view actively running ("incomplete") apps, and from there, by clicking on an app ID link I can get to the Spark UI for a running app.  But as mentioned above, the Spark UI does not update the app state while the app is running.)
After the Spark app completes, clicking on the "History" link for that app in the RM UI does bring up the Spark UI.

Comment: Can you include some screenshots? We might be using "Spark web UI" for two different things.

Comment: Thanks @JacekLaskowski, I added a screenshot of the Spark web UI that is not updating.

Comment: Sorry. No idea. I've got more questions to build a better understanding of the environment than answers so won't help. The only recommendation I have is to stick to Spark 2.2.0 and avoid 1.6.3 which is too old to get much help.

Comment: Try opening Spark UI by driver_ip:port, it should update information very fast. Spark History Server on contrary reads json file(which driver is writing to) from hdfs and checks if it has been updated every 10s and draws new stuff.

Comment: Thanks @ArturSukhenko, this is a good workaround--while the app is running, if I open the driver_ip:port, I can see the updates by refreshing the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Open Spark UI directly by driver_ip:port, it updates information very fast.
Spark History Server on contrary reads json file(which driver is writing to) from hdfs and checks if it has been updated every 10s and parse new events.

Spark History Server is usually used to see finished jobs.

Comment: Although this is a workaround, it doesn't answer the question... which is why the Spark UI isn't updating when viewed from the Yarn UI or the History Server.